# How to echo from a variable using file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to echo the contents of a .php file using file_get_contents.

The filename of which the content is supposed to be echoed from is generated partly by a sql query as below:

`$property_info = '"include/textfiles/' . $properties['expose_info'] . '_info.php"';`

I am then trying to do `echo file_get_contents($property_info);`

For some reason this is not working, but if i'm doing `echo $property_info;` it is outputting the correct file path and when i copy paste that file path back into file_get_contents its also echoing the file contents just how i want it.

So whats the reason for `echo file_get_contents($property_info);` not working? No variables allowed?

Comment: It looks like your file name has double quotes round it (`'"inc...o.php"'`) you don't need them.

Comment: @NigelRen that was it, thanks alot and have a good day sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$property_info = 'include/textfiles/' . $properties['expose_info'] . '_info.php';
```

Not

```
$property_info = '"include/textfiles/' . $properties['expose_info'] . '_info.php"';
```

Reason :

```
Your $property_info contain double qoute inside single quote
```